# How to save frequently used data in android?

Tags: android

This question might seem too common, and I've checked many posts in SO, and other sites too but I didn't get any proper answer to what I'm actually searching

What is the best possible way to save frequently used data?

Here "frequently used data" means all those data which are not worth saving in a database or shared preferences,nor is it suggestible to fetch every time, for example the height and width of the device, the database path,database name

I usually save all these data in a separate class where all the variables are generally static.
I fetch this data when the app starts or in the base activity, and use it wherever its necessary, may be in the activity,or in the adapter, or any parser class, etc..

Everyone knows that static data gets cleared when the phone requires more memory, but even if I save all the data in shared preference too, i can't get a context for the shared preference, or database each and every time i need the data. And these variables must be accessed from any class.

In my app, I name this class as AppConstant, and all my data is saved in static variables within this class, but all the data gets wiped out if I open 5-6 other apps.

So when I open my app again the view is again created in onCreate(), right now I'm checking within the activity, if my required data in the AppConstant is cleared or not, if cleared I'm fetching it from shared preferences.

But I'm hoping for a better alternative. Is there any?
Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You would be interested in https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Answer (score 0):

First, the OS does not "clear" static data when memory is low.  This is what it appears to do, but it is not. If you use a singleton class for example, it will remain intact. What is happening is that the OS is killing your application to free up memory. Upon restart (assuming it happens within about 30 minutes), the OS will restore the state as it was before it was killed. Essentially it restarts the activity that was visible when your app went into the background.  As you know, activities can be killed and easily restarted (happens, for example, when you rotate your device).

However, if you create your singleton in the first activity of your app, it will NOT be present when the OS restarts your app as above - so it appears that the OS has "cleared" the data in your singleton.

Your solution of checking if the static data is there in onCreate() will work and I believe it is the only solution.

Comment: All my activities initiate from a base-activity, if I set all the data in the base activity and not in the first activity of my app, will that help? I didn't try it still now because that will be pretty big change, so just asking if its worth it..

Comment: If you initialize all your static data in your BaseActivity class (in the onCreate() method for example), and you check to see if the data is initialized before doing it, it should work fine.